# Is it ok to short data lines of USB-C

Tags: pcb, usb

USB type C has 2x DP+ and DP- on the connector. When laying out the PCB, is it ok to short each  DP+ and DP- together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DP+ to DP-? No. DP+ to DP+ and DP- to DP-? Yes, absolutely; it's required for the flipover to work.

That is, A6 is connected to B6, A7 connected to B7. As here:

[image]

[image]

(from https://www.reclaimerlabs.com/blog/2017/1/12/usb-c-for-engineers-part-2)

If your USB-C device is a charging port, things are a bit more complicated as far as termination, but the pairs are still wired together in the receptacle. More here: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/4/4803.html

Comment: In fact, it is a must to connect both, or the connector only works in one orientation. Or it does not work in any orientation if connected incorrectly.

Comment: @justme. Not working if connected incorrectly seems to be a central theme to most of electronics.